# Winsock, listen to UDP broadcast from specific interface

Tags: c++, winsock, winsock2

I'm trying to receive UDP broadcasts (DHCP) from a specific network interface in windows.

If I bind to INADDR_ANY I can receive broadcast from all network interfaces. The issue here is that I have to use the mingw (gcc) toolchain so recvmsg is not available. I have not been able to using recvfrom to establish from which network interface the broadcast was received on.

Since it is on windows SO_BINDTODEVICE is also not available.

If I instead bind to the IP of the network interface I want to listen to it seems like broadcasts are not received.

It does not matter if I have to bind to all interfaces as long as I'm able to tell for each received message from which interface it came.

Comment: You should try that with a higher level library like `boost::asio`.